# Total sent in last 7 days from data view

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

I am using this query to pull how many emails were sent in last 7 days.

```
Select count(DISTINCT JobID) AS TotalUniqueSent 
FROM _Sent WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,EventDate,GETDATE()) <= 7
```

But the total number from this query does not match with the tracking records in marketing cloud?

My query is returning 200+ while according to tracking page, there are only 80+ records in last 7 days.

My understanding is that sent data view will create job id only when email is sent out. So, I think unique job ids should give me an idea on how many emails were sent.

Comment: are you querying an enterprise unit (parent) or just a BU? Might explain the discrepancy

Comment: Just my business unit which is a child BU. My understanding is that _SENT dataview only gives our my business unit data only if query is being run in my BU. no?

Comment: Are there triggered sends in your account?

Comment: Yes, but tracking page in marketing cloud also shows triggered sent and I am assuming _sent data view also captures the same?

Comment: In your reports triggered sends are in another folder. Might explain the different

Comment: Ok so triggered sent are only 4..while my total DISTINCT job IDs from sent data view is 200+ while Tracking > Sent shows 80 and triggered shows 4 only.

Comment: I would get support on the line

Comment: I tried pulling the data from Job data view. the 7 days data from Job data view is different from sent data view, why? Could you please advise on this? The distinct jobs from sent data view are 215 while distinct jobs from Job data view are 233, how come?